# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Worklight Starter Dojo example broken?

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I've installed Worklight 6 in an instance of Eclipse Juno and I am wanting to migrate working apps into it from Eclipse Helios and Worklight 5. I am running into some strange problems, possibly because of the transition to Dojo 9 or maybe the new directory structure of the resident Dojo files. So I decided to start with the examples. I use Dojo in my apps, so I downloaded the WorklightStarter_DojoMobile eclipse project and imported it. I did the 'build and deploy' step, and also deployed the WorklightStarterAdapter.

I am trying to run the app in the browser simulator and it appears to be busted. I get the 'about' view but no feeds. I ran it with Firebug and the console shows a lot of peculiar errors.
I won't paste in the network links but a lot of files are not found:

```
WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/apps/services/preview/WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/android/1.0/default/cordova_plugins.json not found 

WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/apps/services/preview/WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/android/1.0/default/dojo/core-web-layer.js not found 

WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/apps/services/api/WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/android/init unauthorized 

/WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/apps/services/preview/WorklightStarter_DojoMobile/android/1.0/default/dojox/mobile/themes/android/android-compat.css
```

Procedure invocation error. White spaces are required between publicId and systemId. Failed to parse the payload from backend (procedure: HttpRequest) with transformation...

Comment: Looking at the directory structure of the example project, I am not seeing a www directory. Uh-oh. This does not look like a project that was set up using WL 6. Did I download the examples from the wrong place? Please tell me that all the WL example code has been restructured and made available as WL 6 projects.

Comment: The Worklight Starter Dojo Edition sample is not fully up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the Worklight Starter Dojo Edition is not fully compatible with Worklight 6; instead, you can use the [Dojo examples from the training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#dojo).